# Buttons are not showing up before svg object

Tags: javascript, html, svg, button

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <button type="button" style="background-color: lightblue;" onclick="makeGraph();">Make Graph</button>
    <button type="button">Save Image</button>
    <svg width="800" height="600"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

This gives a blank area, followed by my buttons.  I click the first button and it draws my graph.
(That code is defined in a function in the head.)

If I comment out the svg, the buttons show up where I expect.  I'm looking for something like an offset to move the svg down the page, so the buttons are on top.  I thought maybe translate would do that, but no luck.

How can I get the svg AFTER the buttons in the display?

Comment: Can you show all code or attach screenshot?

Comment: That's not what I saw, when I styled that svg with CSS, it was after the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should set

```
<svg id='svgGraph' style='display:none' width="800" height="600"></svg>
```

And inside function `makeGraph` you should insert this.

```
document.getElementById('svgGraph').style.display = "block";
```

Comment: That worked! Now I need to figure out why it works! Thanks!

Comment: By default the svg elemnt hide, cause we set `style='display:none'` , when you click, we set this element `style='display:block'` and it shows.

Comment: If we don't set `style='display:none'` the element would have value `block`